# Casting error: The type IList cannot be implicitly converted to IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

My EF Codefirst Model is `Lib`

```
public class Lib
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [PageRemote(PageHandler = "IsKeyExists", HttpMethod = "Get")]
    public string Key { get; set; }
}
```

I want a `combobox` in razor page to select a Lib.
My cshtml code is:

```
<select asp-for="Lib" asp-items="Model.Libs"></select>
```

My PageModel code is :

```
    public IList<Lib> Libs { get; set; }
    public Lib Lib { get; set; }
```

then I get a compiler error

> error CS0266: 无法将类型“System.Collections.Generic.IList”隐式转换为“System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable”。存在一个显式转换(是否缺少强制转换?)

English version (from Google translate):

> error CS0266: The type "System.Collections.Generic.IList
>   " cannot be implicitly converted
>   to "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
>   ". There is an
>   explicit conversion (is a cast missing?)

in wpf combobox has a property named `DisplayMemberPath`, Is there a similar way?

Comment: The code you gave us doesn't show where the problem is.

Comment: my question is how to cast my Libs to select control's asp-items.

Comment: Ahh, I see. But the code you use to cast it, you need to show us here. Just edit your question and add it.

Comment: Seems like this cast is performed internally by ASP as your model has property of IList type. Will it work if you change it to IEnumerable?

Comment: @Tân my question is how to cast

Comment: @balbelias IEnumerable don't work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need pass a compatible type. If you look into the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-3.1#the-select-tag-helper), you'll find that they use `SelectListItem` list. You could refactor the `public IList<Lib> Libs{get;set;}` to `public IList<SelectListItem> Libs{get;set;}`

A another way is to map your list to `SelectListItem` list:

```
@using System.Collections.Generic

<select asp-for="Lib" asp-items="Model.Libs.Select(l=> new SelectListItem{Text=l.Key, Value=l.ID.ToString()})"></select>
```

Comment: yes it can work but i want to know after select, can the bind property `Lib` with type `Lib` set a right object.

Comment: <select asp-for="Lib.ID" asp-items="Model.Libs.Select(l=>new SelectListItem{Text = l.Key, Value = l.ID.ToString() })"></select>
I see. I modify my code link this

Comment: @halong To bind the `Lib` property automatically,  change `public Lib Lib { get; set; }` to `private Lib _lib; [BindProperty] public Lib Lib { get{return this._lib;} set{ this._lib = this.Libs.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ID == value.ID); } }`. Or add a custom `IModelBinder` if you like.